# How can I use a for or while loop with an int declared outside the body?

Tags: c#

I have a loop, like so:

```
        for (i < splitted.Length; i++ != 0)
                {
                    key += '\\' + splitted[i];

                }
```

Depending on an if condition above, i, decdlared outside of the loop's body, may need to be incremented (I am splitting a string into a string[] and then need to join parts of it, but maybe from the 5th index, 6th, etc, depending on the condition in the if clause).

However, C# does not let me write a loop like the above. Can I have a loop like the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an empty initialization clause to allow assignment outside of the `for` loop:

```
int i = 0;
for ( ; i < 10; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        for (;i < splitted.Length; i++)
        {
           if (i!=0)
            key += '\\' + splitted[i];

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A for statement in C# has 3 parts (initializer, condition, and iterator) which are separated by `;`.

```
for (initializer; condition; iterator)
```

Any of these parts can be empty.  The syntax you are giving is only specifying 2 parts and is hence giving a compilation error.  Since the variable is declared outside the loop you want to skip the initializer by leaving it empty

```
for (; i < splitted.Length; i++)
```